# Understanding Do Carmo's simplification for the computation of $N'(0)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Do Carmo's Differential Geometry book. Here:

> [image]
> [image]

It's not clear to me how he obtains $N'(0)=(2u'(0),2v'(0),0)$. Is there a simple way to reach this result or we must really compute the derivative of $N$ along the curve $\alpha$?

I am asking this because I computed it with Mathematica and it gave me something really really complicated:

$$\begin{array}{c}
X= \frac{2 u'(t)}{\sqrt{4 u(t)^2+4 v(t)^2+1}}-\frac{u(t) \left(8 u(t) u'(t)+8 v(t) v'(t)\right)}{\left(4 u(t)^2+4 v(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
Y= \frac{v(t) \left(8 u(t) u'(t)+8 v(t) v'(t)\right)}{\left(4 u(t)^2+4 v(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{2 v'(t)}{\sqrt{4 u(t)^2+4 v(t)^2+1}} \\
Z= -\frac{8 u(t) u'(t)+8 v(t) v'(t)}{2 \left(4 u(t)^2+4 v(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N'(0)$, or rather $(N\circ\alpha)'(0)$, is equal to $\frac{\partial N}{\partial u}(0,0)\,u'(0)+\frac{\partial N}{\partial v}(0,0)\,v'(0).$

Let $N(u,v)=f(u,v)M(u,v)$ with $f(u,v)=\frac1{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+\frac14}}$ and $M(u,v)=(u,-v,1/2).$

$\frac{\partial N}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}M+f\frac{\partial M}{\partial u}$ but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(0,0)=0$, hence $\frac{\partial N}{\partial u}(0,0)$ reduces to $f(0,0)(1,0,0)=(2,0,0).$

Similarly, $\frac{\partial N}{\partial u}(0,0)=(0,-2,0).$

Comment: Please please please do not write $\times$ unless you mean vector cross product. I realize DoCarmo writes that as $\wedge$, but only in elementary school arithmetic is $\times$ used for multiplication!

Comment: ? There is no ambiguity. Well... I shall edit to "please" you ;-)

Comment: Merci mikle fois. We have a lot of beginners on this site (not used to the European $\wedge$ notation) for whom this could be very confusing. It’s not just a matter of pleasing me.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of curve $a$ we have that $a(0)=(u(0),v(0),u^2(0)-v^2(0))=(0,0,0)$, so $u(0)=v(0)=0$ (1). Thus $N'(t)=(\frac{u'(t)f(t)-u(t)f'(t)}{f^2(t)},\frac{v'(t)f(t)-v(t)f'(t)}{f^2(t)},-\frac12 \frac{f'(t)}{f^2(t)})$, where $f(t):=\sqrt {u^2(t)+v^2(t)+\frac 14}$, and finally $N'(t)=(2u'(0),2v'(0),0)$, because of (1) and $f(0)=\frac 12, f'(0)=0$.